# Static construction methods for enums in C#

Tags: c#, enums, static-methods

I'm trying to add static methods to a C# enum. By adding a `static class`, I can create a 'getter' method, which converts the enum value in e.g. a byte. However, I cannot seem to make a 'construction' method, which takes the byte and converts it into an enum. In java, I would use the below code without the separate static class.

Enum code:

```
public enum PoseLocation {

  UP,
  DOWN,
  LEFT,
  RIGHT,
  UP_LEFT,
  UP_RIGHT,
  DOWN_LEFT,
  DOWN_RIGHT

}

public static class PoseLocationMethods {

  public static byte toByte (this PoseLocation location) {
    return (byte)location;
  }

  public static PoseLocation fromByte (byte poseByte) {
    return (PoseLocation)poseByte;
  }

}
```

Method calls:

```
byte poseByte = PoseLocation.UP.toByte (); //OK
PoseLocation fromByte = PoseLocation.fromByte (poseByte); //this does not work
```

Comment: Just try `PoseLocation fromByte = PoseLocationMethods.fromByte(poseByte);`

Comment: Or you can make the other method an extension method (`ToPoseLocation(this byte poseByte)`) and call it as `byte poseByte = ...; var fromByte = poseByte.ToPoseLocation();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to think that `fromByte` is also an extension method...

Look at the declaration carefully:

public static PoseLocation fromByte (byte poseByte)

Do you see the word `this`? No. So it's not an extension method. It's just a normal static method like any other. To call a static method, you need to put the class in which it is declared in in front. In this case, `fromByte` is declared in `PoseLocationMethods`, so you should do:

```
PoselocationMethods.fromByte(1);
```

However, I don't think `fromByte` belongs to the `PoseLocationMethods` class. You might want to write an extension method for `byte`:

```
public static PoseLocation ToPoseLocation(this byte poseByte) {
    return (Poselocation)poseByte;
}
```

Alternatively, get rid of these `To` and `From` methods. I think using a cast is clear enough.

Comment: about: *you should put it in `PoseLocation` enum*: You can't add method to enums in .NET.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek Oops! That's the problem when you know multiple languages, isn't it? Editing now.